# Unable to get Mongo database script output to standard output

Tags: mongodb, docker, redirectstandardoutput, non-interactive, database-scripts

I'm able to to see the output of the count() on a DB collection like below:

```
docker exec -ti STG-mongo-rs mongo --port 27065   --authenticationDatabase '$external' --authenticationMechanism PLAIN -u mydbuser 

> use PP_Metadata;

> db.items.find().count();

947
```

As you can see i get the output as `947`

I now have to get the same output by saving the command `db.items.find().count();` in a script and executing the script on mongo DB

cat script1.txt

```
db.items.find().count();
```

Below is how i execute the script:

```
sudo docker exec -ti STG-mongo-rs mongo --port 27065 --authenticationDatabase '$external' --authenticationMechanism PLAIN -u 'mydbuser' -p 'mypassx' --eval "db = db.getSiblingDB('PP_Metadata'); print(db.getName()); load('audit/db_execute_scripts/script1.txt');"

MongoDB shell version v4.2.20

connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27078/?authMechanism=PLAIN&authSource=%24external&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb

Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("74646e6b-9c39-4986-a413-d83dabcbabf0") }

MongoDB server version: 4.2.20

PP_Metadata

true
```

As you can see the script executes successfully but i get `true` in the output instead of `947`

How can i get the script execution output i.e `947` on command prompt where i run my mongo docker command non-interactively.

The solution i m looking for is to get the output of any script execution on command prompt of non-interactive mongo docker command.

I would eventually use the solution in ansible task.

Comment: I think you have the answer right there: when you used `print` with the database name it went to stdout

Comment: @Joe would the solution be `print(load('audit/db_execute_scripts/script1.txt'))`

Comment: Only if loading the script returns a value.  You might need to put the print call inside the code in that file.

Comment: @Joe the script has only a single line `db.clients.find().count();`. I don't know if this returns a value or not but when the script is executed interactively it does show the count in the output. Please let me know if `print(load('audit/db_execute_scripts/script1.txt'))` will print as was suggested.

Comment: I've never tried to wrap `load` with `print`, I've always put the print inside the script file.